# How to fetch a list of Facebook groups that a user administers after new API changes?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Our app has been approved for Groups API as well as publish_to_groups API.

Earlier, Facebook let you get groups that a given user administered. However, administer field is deprecated in the latest API.

How can we fetch it now?

Comment: /me/groups with the user_managed_groups permission?

Comment: @luschn They have deprecated that permission.

Comment: "The user_managed_groups permission can still be used for testing purposes but cannot be submitted for Login Review." - is it an app just for yourself? in that case, you should still be good. if not...well, if there would be a different way, they would have posted it in the changelog.

Comment: No, it's a live app and we already got reviewed and approved and thus user_managed_groups has been removed.

Comment: then there is no way anymore, i´m afraid.

Comment: I finally found it. There is an undocumented field. For those who run into this issue I am adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it. Earlier, Facebook allowed you to pass a filter with ?administrator=1 GET parameter. However, they still have an undocumented field administrator that you can fetch via ?field=administrator GET parameter. It will let you know if you are an admin or not and you can use it from there.

Comment: so how is the exact api call to get groups you administer then? there is no api call to get all groups, so i don´t understand how asking for the field would solve the question, to be honest.